# How do I have a workflow update a field/column in the current list(InfoPath created list)?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, document-library, excel, calculated-column

I have a column with this formula: `=YEAR(Created)&"-"&(ID)` , the `YEAR(created)` part works as intended but the `ID` part doesnt. It often shows only `2014-` but it should show `2014-50`, the 50 beign the ID.

If i go to the settings of the column containing and save it(no changes are made to the formula) it updates all the current fields and shows `2014-50 (counting up)`. I've did some research on the internet and found out a workflow could fix this. 
I have no clue how to make it.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

You need SharePoint Designer. If you have not used it before, it may be a bit daunting. Here are the general steps:

Open the site with SharePoint Designer, then open the list. In the Settings page, find the panel for the Workflows and add a new workflow.

Edit the workflow and add an action that sets a field's value. You may need a few steps to extract the year from the created date and store it in a variable. SPD is not great on text manipulation functions, but it can be done by writing the date to a variable as an ISO format date and then taking the first four characters in a separate step. The variables and the ID can be concatenated with the String builder and written to the final destination column.

Take little steps, one by one, publish the workflow and run it manually on an item.

When you are happy with the workflow, set the workflow to start when an item is created and publish again.

Here is a good video to get you started. http://sharepoint-videos.com/module-1/sp10creating-a-workflow-on-a-list-using-sharepoint-designer-2010/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still coulnd't get it right :/. Can you help me out a little with an screenshot or example or so :D?

Comment: How far did you get? What you're asking for normally fills a book, or at least a few chapters. I can put in a few screenshots, but I'd need to know what you want to see.

Comment: @tylyn I did find workflow tab, but thats pretty much where it ended :p. All i could get is some basic template's wich didnt work. I've never created a workflow before. :/ If you could show me with some kind of small tut how to keep the a column up to date. Its a calculated column, with the formula `=YEAR(created)&"-"&(ID)`. I want to update this column like every 15 seconds or every minute.

Comment: Sorry, but I really cannot write the book or the seven chapters that you need to know in this answer. You need to learn how to write workflows in SharePoint Designer. So, create a new workflow for the list. Create a variable and populate it with the date in ISO format. Extract the first four characters. Then concatenate them with the ID. Then write that back to the desired field. If this does not make sense to you, I can't help you. You need to learn the basics.  SharePoint Designer steps cannot be copied and pasted here as code.

Comment: I don't want to be unhelpful, but this is like being on one side of the river and needing to get to the other side. The only way to get there is to swim. If you can't swim, you need to learn or you can't cross. Nobody can swim for you. The good news is that there is a lot of material out on the web that will help you learn. Just make a start.